# How to simply the sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{N-n+k}{(N-k+1)(N-k+1)(N-k)}$?

Tags: calculus, summation

Let $N>0$ be a large integer, and $n<N$, then how to simply the following sum
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{N-n+k}{(N-k+1)(N-k+1)(N-k)}.$$
Thank you very much, guys.

Actually for another similar sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(N-k+1)(N-k)}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{N-k}-\frac{1}{N-k+1}=\frac{1}{N-n}-\frac{1}{N}$, I know the trick. But adding one term of such thing, $\frac{N-n+k}{N-k+1}$, it becomes difficult.

So, thanks a million for any clue.

Comment: Do you mean the repeated factor in the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

*I am not sure that you will like it.*

$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{N-n+k}{(N-k+1)^2(N-k)}$$ $$S_n=\frac{n (n-2 N)}{N (n-N)}+(n-2 N-1)\, \big(\psi ^{(1)}(-N)-\psi ^{(1)}(n-N)\big)$$ where appears the first derivative of [the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). I do not think that this could be further simplified. The trouble is that $\psi ^{(1)}(m)$ is undefined for $m\leq 0$.

May be, you could prefer the following. Considering for large values of $N$ $$\frac{N-n+k}{(N-k+1)^2(N-k)}=\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^2+\frac{4 k-n-2}{N^3}+\frac{9 k^2-3 k n-10 k+2
   n+3}{N^4}+\frac{16 k^3-6 k^2 n-28 k^2+8 k n+18 k-3 n-4}{N^5}+\frac{25 k^4-10 k^3
   n-60 k^3+20 k^2 n+60 k^2-15 k n-28 k+4
   n+5}{N^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^7}\right)$$ and now summing from $k=1$ to $k=n$, we should get, as an **approximation**,
$$S_n=\frac{n \left(N \left(6 N^3-3 N+2\right)+1\right)}{6 N^6}+\frac{n^2 \left(6 N^3-6
   N+5\right)}{6 N^6}+\frac{n^3 (N (9 N-2)-10)}{6 N^6}+\frac{n^4 (12 N-5)}{6
   N^6}+\frac{5 n^5}{2 N^6}$$

For sure, we could add more terms for higher accuracy. For illustration purposes, I used $N=1000$ and varied $n$. The following table reports the decimal values of the exact sum and of the ugly approximation.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 50  & 0.00005270  & 0.00005270 \\
 100 & 0.00011173  & 0.00011173 \\
 150 & 0.00017880  & 0.00017876 \\
 200 & 0.00025625  & 0.00025600 \\
 250 & 0.00034721  & 0.00034618 \\
 300 & 0.00045610  & 0.00045276 \\
 350 & 0.00058916  & 0.00057993 \\
 400 & 0.00075548  & 0.00073276 \\
 450 & 0.00096866  & 0.00091727 \\
 500 & 0.00124975  & 0.00114053
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: this doesn't answer the question ; the title specifies "simply" and not the brute calculus ...

Comment: @igael. There is no simple expression. The exact result is the first one I gave.

Comment: if there is no simple expression, the answer is simply "no"

Comment: og N ? is it a log ? yes, perhaps there is no trick ...

Comment: @igael. Sorry for the typo **og** was supposed to be **of**.  On French keyboards, **f** and **g** are next to eachother.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{%
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{N - n + k \over \pars{N - k + 1}\pars{N - k + 1}\pars{N - k}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{2N - n}\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k - N - 1} -
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k - N}} -
\pars{2N - n + 1}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k - N - 1}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{2N - n}n \over N\pars{N - n}} -
\pars{2N - n + 1}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k - N - 1}^{2}}
\end{align}

> Note that

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k + a}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1 + a} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k + 1 + a} - {1 \over k + n + 1 + a}} =
H_{n + a} - H_{a}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k + a}^{2}}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\partiald{}{a}\pars{H_{a} - H_{n + a}} = \Psi\,'\pars{1 + a} -
\Psi\,'\pars{1 + n + a}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

> $\ds{H_{z}}$ is the *Harmonic Number* and $\ds{\Psi\,'}$ is the *Trigamma Function*.

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{%
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{N - n + k \over \pars{N - k + 1}\pars{N - k + 1}\pars{N - k}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{{\pars{2N - n}n \over N\pars{N - n}} -
\pars{2N - n + 1}\bracks{\Psi\,'\pars{-N} - \Psi\,'\pars{-N - n}}}
\end{align}

> Any issue with the *Trigamma's argument signs* can be deal with the *Euler Reflection Formula* or/and the *Recurrence Formula*:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\Psi\,'\pars{z}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\Psi\,'\pars{1 - z} + \pi^{2}\csc^{2}\pars{\pi z}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\Psi\,'\pars{z + 1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\Psi\,'\pars{z} - {1 \over z^{2}}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

With the same method which you have used above you get

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{N-n+k}{(N-k+1)^2(N-k)}=\frac{n(2N-n)}{N(N-n)}-(2N+1-n)\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{( N-k+1)^2}$$

*Hints*:

$\enspace N-n+k=(2N+1-n)-(N-k+1)$

$\enspace \displaystyle \frac{1}{(N-k+1)^2(N-k)}=\frac{1}{N-k}-\frac{1}{N-k+1}-\frac{1}{(N-k+1)^2} $

The closed form for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{( N-k+1)^2}$ is:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{( N-k+1)^2}= \sum\limits_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^2} -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-n} \frac{1}{k^2}=$$$$((\frac{1}{N!} \begin{bmatrix} N+1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix})^2-\frac{2}{N!} \begin{bmatrix} N+1 \\3 \end{bmatrix})-((\frac{1}{(N-n)!} \begin{bmatrix} N-n+1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix})^2-\frac{2}{(N-n)!} \begin{bmatrix} N-n+1 \\3 \end{bmatrix}) $$

where $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}$ is called *unsigned Stirling number of the first kind* .